# hibernate ehcache test fail

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

Currently I'm working on upgrade hibernate from 3.6 to 5.2.3, and I stuck at ehcache, I am using

```
hibernate-core-5.2.3.Final.jar
hibernate-ehcache-5.2.3.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-1.0.0.jar
ehcache-2.10.2.jar
```

the problem is when I run test case individually, the test will pass successfully, but when I run a test suite, it will totally fail every single case, and I configured as:

```
 config.setProperty(Environment.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
```

here is one example of stack trace:

```
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.getService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at com.rtrms.persistence.hibernate.HibernateRepositoryTest.buildSessionFactory(HibernateRepositoryTest.java:583)
    at com.rtrms.persistence.RepositoryTest.testSavingADependentSecurityDoesNotRefreshThatSecurityFromTheDatabase(RepositoryTest.java:893)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:164)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another CacheManager with same name 'yourCacheManager' already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory.start(RegionFactory.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another CacheManager with same name 'yourCacheManager' already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.assertNoCacheManagerExistsWithSameName(CacheManager.java:628)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:392)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:69)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Ehcache 2.x will track open `CacheManager`s and will prevent two with the same name to be open at the same time.

So the most likely error cause in your test is that you do not clean up resources. Since Hibernate is managing the `CacheManager` you probably need to close the `SessionFactory` between tests or open a single one for all the tests.

Comment: all the sessionfactories have been closed, anyway,  all of our test which uses ehcache was using ehcache-core-2.2.0.jar, and hibernate 3, and they were all run successfully, since I migrated from hibernate 3 to 5.2.3, and added hibernate-ehcache, changes config.setProperty(Environment.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");

Comment: all the sessionfactories have been closed, anyway, all of our test that uses ehcache was using ehcache-core-2.2.0.jar, and hibernate 3, and they were all run successfully, since I migrated from hibernate 3 to 5.2.3, and added hibernate-ehcache.jar, changes from config.setProperty(Environment.CACHE_PROVIDER, "org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider");  to config.setProperty(Environment.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"); the error occurs.